# Microsoft SQL Server Won't Connect Through Python

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc

I've looked through some other things but haven't been able to find a working solution.

Here is my code:

```
conn = db.connect("Driver={SQL Server}; Server='Server';Database='Database_DW'; uid='uid'; pwd = 'pwd'")
```

I run this code and I get the following error:

> DatabaseError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.')

I'm really at a loss here. I can log in fine through the SQL Server Client with the exact some credentials.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2017/07/27/sql-connectivity-troubleshooting-checklist/

Comment: It's not a SQL Server issue. It's an issue with the pypyodbc library that I'm having trouble with. SQL Server is running fine. I said that in the comment.

Comment: Parameters in connection strings are usually not quoted. And what is *db*? Please include a fuller code block and not line snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adjusting connection strings as parameter values are not quoted. Right now, pypyodbc is attempted to find the *'Server'* (quotes included) server.

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};server=servername;database=databasename;" + \
                        "UID=username;PWD=***")
```

Alternatively, use keyword arguments:

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}", host="servername", database="database",
                        uid="username", pwd="***")
```